Angular can not upload file via formData
I am trying to send my excel file to my asp.net core backend from angular. I can do it in postman easily
Postman Screenshot
But when I try in angular I get error below:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "file": [
            "The file field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-b1e599ba9962b10481f704228daeddae-372bd43ca76db219-00"
}

My angular http request:
uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseApiUri}api/FileLoad/LoadKeepaFile`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
  }

My component ts
onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    if (this.file) {
      this.fileName = this.file.name;
    }
  }

  uploadFile() {
    if (this.file) {
      this.uploadProgress = 0;
      this.uploadCancelled = false;

      this.productManagementService.uploadFile(this.file).subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.uploadProgress = Math.round(100 * (event.loaded / (event.total ?? 1)));
        } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.uploadProgress = null;
          // Handle the response from the server here
          console.log('File uploaded successfully', event.body);
        }
      }, error => {
        console.error('Upload failed', error);
        this.uploadProgress = null;
      });
    }
  }

  cancelUpload() {
    this.uploadCancelled = true;
    this.uploadProgress = null;
    this.fileName = null;
    this.file = null;
  }

My request payload when I send request
Chrome Developer Screenshot

I couldn't find solution so I decided to use axios instead. It works well
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
};

 // Axios isteğini bir Promise olarak oluştur
 const axiosPromise = this.axios.post(`${environment.baseApiUri}api/FileLoad/LoadKeepaFile`, formData, { headers});

 // Promise'i Observable'a dönüştür
 return from(axiosPromise.then((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
  if(response?.data?.isSuccess){
    this.toastService.success(response?.data?.message);
  }else{
    this.toastService.error(response?.data?.message);
  }
 }));


According to this discussion on GitHub, it should work when removing the Content-Type header:
uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseApiUri}api/FileLoad/LoadKeepaFile`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
    });
  }

Angular automatically handles the content type when passing a body which is an instance of FormData.

I tried it but same error
